# How to redirect using url

Tags: html, networking, redirect

I have obtained hosting space and they registered domain(say **www.abc.com**) with an ip(say **http://1.2.3.4/~myspace**) for me to. But i want to use it as two websites. i.e. if i type www.abc.com then it show open the index.html file inside a folder called "friend" in my public_html dir. And when i type **http://1.2.3.4/~myspace** it shud as normally open the index.html in **root**.!

Is it possible to

1. redirect to the inner folder when user types domain name
2. not redirect inner folder (but rather open the root's index) when user enters "ip address". Help me out here

---

@dan360: yeah i did the scripting.. got it dude!! very much thanks.!

just incase anyone comes across this.. here's the code I used

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
if (top.location == "http://www.abc.com/")
top.location = "http://www.abc.com/friend/index.htm";
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Now i can use my ip to access my site alone

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question.

Comment: Sounds like an Apache VirtualHost problem to me, or probably something you'd do in cPanel since this is a hosting account. Where's the programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but you need to do some scripting.

You can read the url and domain with asp, php, javascript and many other scripting languages.
All you need to do is read it and make a decision to redirect if you are on www.abc.com.

However you should note that when the redirect happens without some kind of url masking, the url would read www.abc.com/friend/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a web host and not a vps or ps this can vary a lot depending on how your account is set up (some cases they moght not even let you). you'll have to ask technical support for your web host.